# Scheme: Procedure that causes random errors at a specific rate

Tags: scheme

This is the last homework question I have, and it stumped the tutor as well. I quite honestly have no idea where to go with this one and have exhausted help here at school. The question i to:

Define a procedure test-most-common which takes a number repetitions, a number rate, and a list of 0s and 1s original. The procedure should first produce repetitions copies of the list original. Then it should simulate the transmission of each copy over a noisy channel by introducing random errors every rate elements on average. Finally it should check that the list of most common values matches the original input list.

I all ready have a function written out that takes the most-common element (big thanks to Oscar for that one!) So I really need some help on the meat of this one. I know you want to make use of random and have a specific rate for that random. If the error occurs I know you want to change a 0 to a 1 and a 1 to a 0. I also have all ready written a function that will repeat the original over at the amount of repetitions given which is all I have so far for this problem and that is given here:

```
(define repeated-list 
 (lambda (rep org)
  (cond
   [(equal? rep 0) '()]
   [else (cons org (repeated-list (sub1 rep) org))])))

(define noisy-channel
 (lambda (rep-org rate)
  (cond
   [(null? rep-org) '()]
   [else (cons (noisy-helper (car rep-org) rate) (noisy-channel (cdr rep-org) 
    rate))])))


(define noisy-helper
 (lambda (rep-org rate)
  (cond
    [(null? rep-org) '()]
     [**(here is where I'm stuck)**])))


(define test-most-common
 (lambda (rep rate org)
  (equal? (most-common(noisy-channel (repeated-list rep org) rate)) org)))
```

I marked down where I am stuck. It is at that point I believe I need to do the random function and some math (maybe?) to get it where the bits are actually flipped.

Comment: I think you'll need to show more code in order for this not to be closed as off-topic.  You might start by breaking down this task into several subtasks.  Your signal is a list of 0s and 1s.  You need to be able to produce copies of the signal that have random errors injected (are the errors simply flipped bits?), and then you need to compute some metrics of the noisy signal.

Comment: Are you working in one of the pure Schemes (e.g., R5RS) or in Racket?  This might be significantly more difficult if you don't have access to a random number generator.

Comment: I'm working in Racket using #lang racket . I'll add some more code of my work I've been trying to do. The errors are literally turning some 1's to 0's and 0's to 1's.

Comment: So the only need for randomness is determining _which_ bits in the signal to flip, not adjusting them by fractional values.  It sounds like if you just generate random numbers that average out to `rate`, then you can just use them to figure out which bits to flip in the signal.

Comment: The code was just added, and I think that is the road I was going down, I'm just confused at the point of actually finding the random rate and how to flip the bits due to that rate.

Comment: Well, you said that the function takes the rate as an input, so you don't have to find it;  it's given to you.  There's a section about [Random Numbers](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#(part._.Random_.Numbers)) in the Racket manual.  If you wanted the average time between errors to be `n`, you could generate random numbers `r` in the range `[-k,k]` for some `k`, and then, once you picked one error location `l`, let `l+r`.  You may need to determine whether there's supposed to be some specific variance in your numbers, and whether it's average time between errors, or

Comment: that there's an average number of errors per every [some number] of element in the signal, or something else.  If you can pin down how the noise is supposed to be generated, it won't be too hard to implement it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

First, your repeat org doesn't behave as you described.  It repeats a single element, not a list.  You will actually need a helper function to make repeated lists, or use the append function:

```
(define repeated-list 
  (lambda (rep org)
    (cond
      [(equal? rep 0) '()]
      [else (append org (repeated-list (sub1 rep) org))])))
```

Second, if you want to write a function that changes a bit with a certain probability:

```
(define change-list
  (lambda (mypoorlist rate)
    (cond
      [(empty? mypoorlist) '()]
      ;; if rate exceeds a random value from 0..1
      ;; then toggle the first value (1 - first value)
      [(> rate (random)) (cons (- 1 (car mypoorlist)) (change-list (cdr mypoorlist) rate))]
      ;; otherwise just keep going
      [else (cons (car mypoorlist) (change-list (cdr mypoorlist) rate))]
     )))
```

For most common, just write out a function to find that recursively.  One easy way if you are dealing with 0/1 lists is just to add the whole thing and see if it is greater or less than length/2.

Your question is strange though, if you randomly change values then you are not guaranteed that the most common elements will be unchanged.  If you have a high enough rate (more than 50%), it even becomes unlikely.

Perhaps if you post the EXACT question we can help you more.

Comment: Sadly that is exactly word for word all we have for the question.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was curious about this I solved this problem and am going to show the code of how I submitted it on my homework. I messed up by not doing the recursion in the final function so that itd check every nested list, but thats an easy fix.

```
(define repeated-list 
 (lambda (rep org)
  (cond
   [(equal? rep 0) '()]
   [else (cons org (repeated-list (sub1 rep) org))])))

(define noisy-helper
 (lambda (rep-org rate)
  (cond
      [(null? rep-org) '()]
      [(< (random 100) rate)
       (cond
         [(equal? (car rep-org) 0) (cons 1 (noisy-helper (cdr rep-org) rate)
                                         )]
         [(equal? (car rep-org) 1) (cons 0 (noisy-helper (cdr rep-org) rate)
                                         )])]
      [else (cons (car rep-org) (noisy-helper (cdr rep-org) rate))])))


(define noisy-channel
 (lambda (rep-org rate)
   (cond
    [(null? rep-org) '()]
    [else (cons (noisy-helper (car rep-org) rate) (noisy-channel (cdr rep-org)
                                                               rate))])))

(define test-most-common
 (lambda (rep rate org)
   (equal? (most-common org)(most-common(car (noisy-channel 
                                           (repeated-list rep org) 
                                           rate))))))
```